# absolute search for zii.widgets.grid.CGridView

Tags: yii

I am new to YII and zii.widgets.grid.CGridView stuffs. I have few modification in a old project to do.

$model->search()  activate search in the data grid view but does partial search.

How can I change that to absolute search ?

Thanks 
Ab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your search function in the model, you probably have lines like:

```
$criteria->compare('attributename',$this->attributename,true);
```

Change the third parameter to `false`, and you won't get partial matches:

```
$criteria->compare('attributename',$this->attributename,false);
```

Check [CDbCriteria compare function](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail).

**Edit:** to do begins/starts with search(i.e keyword%), you can again modify the compare function slightly:

```
$criteria->compare('attributename',$this->attributename.'%',false,'AND',false);
// that translates to keyword%, we need the fifth parameter to be false, otherwise % is escaped
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your advice.

Lookes Like I explained in the wrong way.

I wanted the search to work in keyword%   and not %keyword%.

Means I didnt want it to compare from any part of the text but start from begining 

like    if we have data   abcd,bdac,accc

and I search a       1st and 3rd data should come

More like getting data starting from particular aplhabet.

Thanks !!
Ab

Comment: user   addCondition ($condition, $operator='AND') instead

BUt Thanks for your support

Cheers !!

Comment: glad to help. let me know how you did it with addCondition.